# How can you attach many discord embeds to one message?

Tags: discord.js

I'm working on a discord bot, and I have a command, listing objects.
Apparently, after listing many messages in seconds, discord has put a delay before allowing to send the next couple of ten messages.
Is there a way to send many embeds in one message?

```js
msg.reply(embed1, embed2);
```

I've tried using the line above, where `msg` is the command message, but the bot responded with:

```
[1:18 PM] BOT Bot: [object Object]
Embed 2
Content
```

Embed 2 was sent, but instead of the first embed the bot wrote `[object Object]`

I noticed that the sending messages discord accepts two parameters - the original text message and the embed.

I also tried combining all embeds to one object, but that didn't work:

```js
msg.reply("Text Message", { embed1, embed2 });
```

I expect for the bot to list all of my objects in one message, in the correct order.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, sending multiple embeds in a single message (*as a Client*) is not possible within the Discord API. A simple solution could be to send multiple messages containing each embed in order, creating a similar appearance.

As [JackRed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8040287/jackred) has pointed out, it's *possible* within Webhooks to send 10 embeds per message, but in most cases it would be very inconvenient and illogical.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Yes, this is sad!

Comment: what about using a webhook? They have a 10 embeds limit / message

Comment: Not sure what's "illogical" about it. Discord included this functionality quite specifically. If you need to track a message, do you find it more logical to track up to 10 than 1?

Comment: @arkon Creating and maintaining many webhooks across different channels solely for this purpose is not ideal. Sure, tracking 1 message is simpler than tracking 10 messages. But do you find it more logical to track possibly thousands of webhooks rather than none? Also, webhooks cannot be created for DM channels. Even more, the message's author is not a "normal" user client so it appears differently in Discord. In my opinion, all of this makes such a solution illogical for most use cases. However, I haven't used the Discord API in a long time so there could be far better solutions by now.